# codeigniter Type: ArgumentCountError

Tags: php, codeigniter

i found this error

> Type: ArgumentCountError
>
> Message: Too few arguments to function KeluhanMav::tangani(), 0 passed in /opt/lampp/htdocs/cctv/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected

how to fix it?

my controller

```
public function tangani($id_keluhan)
    {
        $data['jeniskeluhan']=$this->Keluhanmav_model->getJenisKeluhan();
        $data['data_keluhan']=$this->Keluhanmav_model->showKeluhan();
        $data['get_camera']=$this->Keluhanmav_model->getCameraById($id_camera);
        $data['get_keluhan']=$this->Keluhanmav_model->getKeluhanById($id_keluhan);
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        // var_dump($data['get_camera']);

        // $this->form_validation->set_rules('tgl_keluhan', 'tgl_keluhan', 'trim|required');
        // $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_jeniskeluhan', 'id_jeniskeluhan', 'trim|required');
        // $this->form_validation->set_rules('isi_keluhan', 'isi_keluhan', 'trim|required');

        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
            $this->load->view('header/headermav', $data);
            $this->load->view('keluhan/tangani_keluhan', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer/footer', $data);
        }else{
            $this->Keluhan_model->editKeluhan($id_keluhan);
            redirect('HomeMav','refresh');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is whatever is calling this function, you are expecting the parameter `$id_keluhan` to be passed but it isn't being passed to this function.